# Can we export controls to PowerPoint in windows 8 store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

As we are developing an windows store app, as of requirement we need to export the charts or grids which were presented in the application to PowerPoint. As previously(previous projects sliverlight or asp.net) we used OpenXML and COM objects for exporting, but I haven’t found any COM objects dll’s in the references nor OpenXML dll’s not working when I added to references. Is there any way to export the charts or grid controls to PowerPoint or why it doesn’t support it.

Comment: There does not appear to be a simple "convert the control into Powerpoint". I also want to preface the next advice with "I'm no expert."  From my research and experience, you have 3 options: 1) Recreate the charts/tables using the OpenXML standard inside of powerpoint. 2) Export the tables to Excel, then use its charting/table functions to import them into powerpoint. 3) Use a direct-x hook like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) to turn the controls into images and add the images into the Powerpoint.

Comment: @NateDiamond actually OpenXML and COM objects for the excel or ppt won't work in the windows store app and as we are developing the app in C# only i'm unaware of DirectX development.

Comment: Check out the link to SharpDx I posted. It will let you hook into DirectX using .NET (and C#).

Comment: Thanks for reply's i done using openxml which i wrote code in the webservice and used in the design.

Comment: R U using C# or javascript? I use http://www.highcharts.com/ charts for my Windows Store WinJS apps. They do have a feature to export the rendered chart to excel... have not tryied though

Comment: i'm using c# and telerik chart for windows store apps.

Answer (score 1):

We might as well start with the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office by Microsoft. This is a nice SDK, but it is not compiled for Windows Store Apps. Don't try.

> > Unfortunately the OpenXML SDK 2.0 and 2.5 rely on .Net Framework namespaces (e.g. System.Xaml) which are not available for Windows 8 Store apps. So at the moment there is no way to use the OpenXML SDK in WinRT. [Cite](http://knabben.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/openxml-sdk-and-windows-8-store-app/)

There really is no solution for you at this time. As you know, the charts themselves are simply XML and I suppose you could parse and duplicate this XML; that would get you a kind of integration. After all, that's what the SDK did for you. Sorry though.

Now you know.

Comment: Thanks nixon, i have implemented the openxml in the webservice and called the webservice method in the app.Now it working fine.